# Question for Accessing MS Graph Using Client Credentials One Drive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-devops, oauth-2.0

I can't seem to grasp my error

this is the result of the JSON return

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2022-03-16T13:43:15",
        "request-id": "7dc60220-68fb-411f-a3e7-9d2eac74483a",
        "client-request-id": "7dc60220-68fb-411f-a3e7-9d2eac74483a"
         }
    }
}
```

it's not telling me anything

I don't know what's wrong,

I looked at the token
and I have roles

by the way I have client_credentials token

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root/children
```

**Update:**
I tried on
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
using this api
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root
it works on that website,

But in postman it won't work,
is it because I used client credentials token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified which drive to open.
The URL should be like this for a user's drive:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/drive/root/children
```

There are other examples on the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
Note you cannot use `/me` as you are using client credentials, which means that the token does not identify a user.
You must instead use `/users/{user-id}` for user drives.

Comment: I tried others like
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root

and still doesn't work

but it works on
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: On Graph Explorer you are not using a client credentials token though, it actually has your user info in the token there.

Comment: yeah, which is why I'm trying to use postman, to use the client credentials

and I get an unknown error,
I'm at wits end on solving this issue,

because, the error doesn't give me any clue where to start looking for a fix

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: yes different error now
 "message": "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.",
   
I'm probably going to create a different question now, thank you :)